# Button not getting enabled upon selection of value in dropdown Selenium

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, pageobjects

There is a "Continue" button in my application which is enabled upon selection of a value in a dropdown i.e. "Year".

When using Selenium for this, even after selecting this value, the button is not enabled, and hence the test fails, since Selenium is not able to click on the disabled button.

When this dropdown is manually selected the button is enabled

How can I handle this scenario using Selenium WebDriver

Comment: try to add wait before clicking the button it will work

Comment: Did that already, does not work

Comment: Can you share the HTML for the dropdown, and the WebDriver code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hi just after selection value form dropdown implement this piece of code before the click

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your path= 
when button is disabled as on enable path will change")));
```

// now your click code for the button

or also you can try like below

just after selecting value form the dropdown and just before the button click please click some where else on the page ,some time this wasy alos helps

**UPDATE**

after going through your html for the button there is a slight difference in the class name please look closely

```
Class name when button is disabled  = LA-right LA-btn payment-continue
Class name when button is enabled   = LA-right LA-btn payment-continue enable
```

so please use the first scenario with xpath  as //*[@class='LA-right LA-btn payment-continue']
or css selector = By.cssSelector(".LA-right.LA-btn.payment-continue")
this will help now i guess

Comment: Ok will try to use this

Comment: Tried clicking somewhere on the page, it does not work either

Comment: This does not work either since the XPATH of both the enabled and disabled button or link remains the same i.e. //*[@id="payment"]/div[2]/div/a

Comment: Copying link HTML  Disabled:
<a data-bind="click: $root.acordeonSteps.nextStep,clickBubble: false, css:{ enable: $data.isValid }, text: $root.copies().PaymentMethods.ContinueButton" class="LA-right LA-btn payment-continue">Continue</a>

Enabled:
<a data-bind="click: $root.acordeonSteps.nextStep,clickBubble: false, css:{ enable: $data.isValid }, text: $root.copies().PaymentMethods.ContinueButton" class="LA-right LA-btn payment-continue enable">Continue</a>

Comment: ElementNotVisible Exception